# Tensorflow loss converging but model fails to predict even on train data

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

Using ANN with Tensorflow to train a simple known equation Y=Sin(X) or Y=Cos(X). My loss function is converging properly.
[Loss function convergence graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjkjD.png). If loss function converges it means model has fitted well to my training dataset.

However, when I predict passing in argument training set itself, model fails to predict even train data which is strange.
[Here it can be seen that after 200th value there model shows no training at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irf9w.png)
If the loss has converged then model should fit the train dataset perfectly but that is not happening here. What is wrong in my code?

```
X = np.linspace(0,10*np.pi,1000)
Y = np.sin(X)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(500,input_shape=(1,),activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01)
model.compile(optimizer=opt,loss='mse')
r= model.fit(X.reshape(-1,1),Y,epochs=100)
plt.plot(r.history['loss'])
Yhat = model.predict(X.reshape(-1,1)).flatten()
plt.plot(Y)
plt.plot(Yhat)
```

Comment: Your loss is still around 0.5 and it is relatively high. So, you can not expect the model to predict good results. It can be accounted as a type of data which can be handled with timeseries models. In addition to @AbhishekPrajapat's answer, I recommend to try RNN and LSTM layers.

Comment: generically, any method you can suggest to know what is an acceptable level of loss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the nature of your data.

> It made me remember the old paper which showed that the ANN can't compute even the XOR

Anyway the reason here is that your model is shallow and shallow networks are much less efficient than deep networks. To put in perspective a model like below

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(20,input_shape=(1,),activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(20,activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
```

Will likely perform better even though it has only `1/3` of the parameters of the original model and that is cause the deeper you go the more complex representations can the model create. The core thing to remember is

> THE DEEP LEARNING MODEL DON'T BUILD NON-LINEAR DECISION BOUNDARIES as EACH AND EVERY
> UNIT IS FUNDAMENTALLY DESIGNED TO CREATE SOME LINEAR DECISION BOUNDARY. so what does
> it do? IT FROM STACKING THOSE LINEAR DECISION BOUNDARIES MAKE A REPRESENTATION OF
> DATA WHICH IS LINEARLY SEPARABLE.

Also, the most important things is to know your data. In this case using the `Probabilistic Models` will give almost perfect results. You can easily implement those using `TensorFlow probability`.

Comment: Are you sure? I tested the model in the question, and your proposed model, both with 2000 epochs. Question model gave loss 0.3451, and your model gave me 0.3454.

Comment: @Kaveh yes it did perform better in my case. Just that I used I bit more training samples. In case of `500` units the training saturates but in case of `20 and 20` it goes much lower.

Comment: Any particular reason for using all-capitals in a whole paragraph (which feels like shouting)?

Comment: @desertnaut No reason. Was just a bit sleepy and didn't focus that I am writing all caps and was too lazy to change.

Comment: I tried adding the layers and I was able to reduce the loss and fit better. thanks